# total size and total number of object in IBM Bluemix object store

Tags: ibm-cloud, openstack, object-storage

I'm using an IBM Bluemix Object Store.
Now I want to know how many files are in the object store and what the total size of these object are within a container.

When I try to get the info of a container (/v1/​{account}​/​{container}​) I only get the objects back with a maximum of 10000 objects.

Is the an other URL which I have to use to get the total number of objects and the total size of a container.

Arjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `curl` command will return you an array of JSON objects, where each object has the following details of your containers:

- Number of objects (files)
- Total size in bytes
- Name of the container

  `curl -i https://dal.objectstorage.open.softlayer.com/v1/{account}?format=json -X GET -H "X-Auth-Token: xxxxx"`

It returns the following information (see last line for the array of JSON objects, but information in available in the header as well):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 143
X-Account-Object-Count: 6
X-Account-Storage-Policy-Standard-Container-Count: 3
X-Timestamp: 1462461311.74826
X-Account-Meta-Temp-Url-Key: xxxxxx
X-Account-Storage-Policy-Standard-Object-Count: 6
X-Account-Bytes-Used: 8767182
X-Account-Container-Count: 3
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Account-Storage-Policy-Standard-Bytes-Used: 8767182
x-account-project-domain-id: xxxxxx
Date: Wed, 18 May 2016 01:31:01 GMT

[{"count": 1, "bytes": 7873373, "name": "logs"}, {"count": 3, "bytes": 378749, "name": "test"}, {"count": 2, "bytes": 515060, "name": "test2"}]
```

Please note I masked some sensitive data above for security reasons.

You can see the `curl` command below when you run `swift` cli in debug mode:

```
$ swift --debug list -lt
```

If you need more information about how to setup `swift` cli for your Object Storage see the documentation in the link below:

https://new-console.eu-gb.bluemix.net/docs/services/ObjectStorage/objectstorge_usingobjectstorage.html#using-swift-cli

Comment: Alex da Silva,  Tx.  that was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python you could do something like the following:

```
conn = swiftclient.Connection(
        key=password,
        authurl=auth_url,
        auth_version='3',
        os_options={"project_id": project_id,
                             "user_id": user_id,
                             "region_name": region_name})

#List objects in a container, and prints out each object name, the file size, and last modified date

for container in conn.get_account()[1]:
    for data in conn.get_container(container['name'])[1]:
        print 'object: {0}\t size: {1}\t date: {2}'.format(data['name'], data['bytes'], data['last_modified'])
```

[Source](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/1b48459f-4091-43cb-bca4-37863606d989/entry/Use_Python_to_access_your_Bluemix_Object_Storage_Service_with_Keystone_v3?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Swift CLI.

**# swift stat**  *show account details*

```
Account: AUTH_ad1e25aee7464b35ad82dd5c19725a4a
Containers: 4710
Objects: 53
Bytes: 52446270
...
```

**# swift stat my_container**  *shows container details*

```
Account: AUTH_ad1e25aee7464b35ad82dd5c19725a4a
Container: my_container
Objects: 1
Bytes: 1437696
...
```